# Aborting nested ajax call / do promises improve this code?

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise

I have an object which exposes a method for getting some data asynchronously. The method runs two AJAX requests, but the second request is dependent on the first request and so it needs to wait for the first to succeed.

Outside of the object, nobody needs to know that two AJAX requests are happening. However, I do need to be able to abort the request. This has resulted in me introducing a race-condition.

Here's some pseudo-code:

```
function foo (options) {
    var jqXHR = $.ajax({
        success: function(){
            console.log('jqXHR success');

            var innerJqXHR = $.ajax({
                success: options.success,
                error: options.error
            }); 
        }
    });

    return jqXHR;
}


var jqXHR = foo({
    success: function(){
        console.log('innerJqXHR success');
    }
});

//  Abort, fails if jqXHR success has already been called.
jqXHR.abort();
```

If the abort method is ran after the first callback has succeeded then the second callback will continue.

What's a good way to approach this issue? I have a sneaking suspicion that this is the sort of thing promises are good at, but I wasn't able to see how they could be used here.

Comment: Similar question here (by same author): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401679/rejecting-inner-promise-after-initial-promise-has-succeeded/28401933

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I just wasn't using promises and I think that that example was a bit more of a real world example than this contrived one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
function foo (options) {
    return $.ajax({...}).then(function(result){
        return $.ajax({... }); // note the return
    });
}
```

Which would let you do:

```
foo(...).then(function(result){
    // handle result
}); // can also add fail handler
```

This works because you can return a promise from a promise which will cause it to wait for the inner promise.

Comment: I thought the main point of the OP's question was that they needed to be able to abort the operation at any time during it.  Quoting from the question: ***"However, I do need to be able to abort the request".*** How does this offer that?