# Rejecting inner promise after initial promise has succeeded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have a function which issues two async requests before yielding some data.

The caller of the method does not need to know about its implementation details. All the caller needs is:

- The data returned from the second request.
- The ability to call abort and not be returned data.

This is complicated by the fact that abort can be called after the first promise is done. The second request is already in-flight, but the caller has yet to receive data. So, the caller assumes it can call abort, but rejecting the first promise will have no effect.

I work around this issue with the following, but it feels pretty hacky. Am I missing something?

```js
var ajaxOptions = {
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search',
  data: {
    part: 'id',
    key: 'AIzaSyDBCJuq0aey3bL3K6C0l4mKzT_y8zy9Msw',
    q: 'Hello'
  }
};

function search(options) {
  var jqXHR = $.ajax(ajaxOptions);

  var innerJqXHR = null;
  jqXHR.then(function(data, statusText, jqXHR) {
    innerJqXHR = $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
    innerJqXHR.done(options.done);
    innerJqXHR.fail(options.fail);

    return innerJqXHR;
  }, options.fail);

  return {
    promise: jqXHR,
    innerPromise: innerJqXHR,
    fullAbort: function() {
      jqXHR.abort();

      if (innerJqXHR !== null) {
        innerJqXHR.abort();
      }
    }
  }
}

var searchReturn = search({
  done: function() {
    console.log('inner done');
  },
  fail: function() {
    console.log('inner or outer fail');
  }
});

searchReturn.fullAbort();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it is not clear how it should work. What does it mean : The ability to call abort and not be returned data.

Comment: I was going to offer you a simpler way to do this, but the code isn't making sense to me.  You're executing `$.ajax(ajaxOptions)` twice one after the other.  I would have thought your second ajax call would be different than the first and would incorporate the data returned from the first, but your code doesn't show that.

Comment: I was just using the AJAX call as an example as it wasn't pertinent to my problem. In practice, each AJAX call is different and transforms the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code looks a little like pseudo-code (unanswered questions in it for me), the best I can offer is a framework of an idea.  The general idea is that you return two things from your search function, a promise that is resolved only when both ajax calls are resolved and an abort function that can be called to abort the process.

```
function search(options) {
    var activeAjax = $.ajax(args for first ajax call).then(function(data) {
        // second ajax call changes activeAjax so abort will work
        // on the active ajax call
        activeAjax = $.ajax(args for second ajax call).then(function(data) {
            activeAjax = null;
            // collect your final data here and return it
            // this will be the resolved value of the final promise
            return finalData;
        });
        return activeAjax;
    });

    return {
        promise: activeAjax,
        abort: function() {
            if (activeAjax) {
                activeAjax.abort();
            }
        }
    };
}

// usage:
var searchInProgress = search(...);
searchInProgress.promise.then(function(data) {
    // search finished successfully, answer is in data
}, function(err) {
    // either one of the promises failed
});

// and, at any time, you can call searchInProgress.abort();
```

Comment: Yeppers. This seems like the only solution. The other thought I had was overriding the return promise's abort function and overriding it with one that aborts whichever the active ajax is, but I think that would be more confusing. I was just hoping there was a way to abort no matter what part of the chain of promises was active, but I don't think there is! :)

Comment: @SeanAnderson - abort is not a standard feature of jQuery promises and chaining/nesting promises like we're doing here creates more promises that won't necessarily have custom methods on them so I thought it was safest to NOT try to add an abort method directly to the promise, thus returning our own object that has an `abort()` method on it which we know is safe.

Comment: For sure, I agree with the decision. I just am (slightly?) surprised that promises support chaining execution with .then(), but do not support chain-rejecting.

Comment: @SeanAnderson - jQuery promises themselves facilitate observers.  They don't let you change the outcome.  You would normally need access to the Deferred object in order to change the outcome.  A jqXHR object is not strictly a promise.  It is a merging of the original jqXHR object with promise methods added.  Thus the `abort()` method on the jqXHR object is not really a promise method, but rather a jqXHR method specific to this Ajax use.